# Organizing the code for apartment modelling in C++ with OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, architecture

I am making an apartment with C++ and openGl. I have made basic walls, roof and floor by just declaring points in the drawing function and everything of course works but code is messy and adding furniture this way would of course be very painful. So I am asking how should I organize my objects and format drawing function?

Here's the current code:

```
// Floor and roof of room 1
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glNormal3f(0.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glEnd();

// Walls
glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glNormal3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0,1.0,1.0);

    glNormal3f(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glNormal3f(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.0, 0.5);

    glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glEnd();

And so on for room 2 and door spots..
```

Any places to read about this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3d modelling software, e.g. [→Blender](http://www.blender.org/) to define your geometry etc. Then I recommend to use [→Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) to load the exported model. Also recommend to avoid the old fixed-function pipeline – write your own little scenegraph engine and manage your matrices and 3d math with [→GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)